# Can I use <T implements Comparable> or just <Comparable>

Tags: java, generics, comparable

Can I use `<T implements ..>` instead of `<T extends...>`?

Can't I use `<Comparable>` just without extends/implements?

Why or why not?

```
class SomeClass
{
   public static <T extends Comparable> somemethod(T[] a)
   {
        // do stuff
   }
}
```

Comment: sorry i am editting the question

Comment: Use the revision with my correct formatting. The formatting thinks `<` is the start of a tag so you need code ticks around it or use `&lt;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Comparable` is a *generic* type (and an *interface*) so you must *extend* and you cannot *implement* - it is how Java generics work, also your method is missing a return signature.  You could use a [Lower Bounded Wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html) like

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T[] somemethod(T... a) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    return a;
}
```

which should work as you expect<sup>1</sup>. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(somemethod(4, 3, 1, 2)));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(somemethod(new Integer[] { 8, 7, 6, 5 })));
}
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[5, 6, 7, 8]
```

<sup>1<sub>Here, a [variadic (varargs)  function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) that sorts but you can use an array if you like.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you. Helpful and understandable